# Video decoding and rendering library for XLib

Tags: linux, video, x11, xlib

Currently what I have a Linux application that was written using Xlib and I needed to add video playing capabilities into it.

What libraries would you recommend that I could use for video decoding and rendering that works well with Xlib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options are plentiful.

- [xine-lib](http://www.xine-project.org/).
- [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) (works best with [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/)-based programs).
- [Phonon](http://phonon.kde.org/) (works best with [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/)-based programs).
- [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).
- [libVLC](http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC).
- [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) + [XEmbed](http://standards.freedesktop.org/xembed-spec/xembed-spec-latest.html).

Xine is probably the easiest (easier than FFmpeg, anyhow) without requiring anything beyond itself and Xlib.  There's a short, complete [example](http://www.xine-project.org/samplecode) in under 180 lines of actual code.

> muxine is a very small player that just creates a X11 window and play a given stream MRL. Source code: [muxine.c](http://www.xine-project.org/samples/muxine.c).
>
> You can compile muxine with:
>
> ```
> gcc -Wall -O2 `xine-config --cflags`
>     -o muxine muxine.c `xine-config --libs`
> ```

On the other hand, using MPlayer+XEmbed is pretty easy too, much easier if you don't care to have much control over the video playback.  Create a X11 window, and run `mplayer -wid <window-id>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using either FFMpeg or Mplayer.